# recursion on sql many sql tables

Tags: sql, sql-server, recursion

i have a set of (currently) 7 tables, all with the exact same structure with a running number on their names like:
tbl_1_items, tbl_2_items, tbl_3_items...

each table is build like this:
key, parentKey, url, other columns... table1 of course does not contains a parentKey.

i need a recursive query/SP, if its even possible, to run from a certain level and key down until i find a url that is not null, and i will run only the 1st result down.

example:
i send level 2 key 1 so it will do this:

```
SELECT url FROM 'tbl_' + @level + 'items' WHERE url IS NOT NULL
```

now if there are no results it will do

```
SELECT url FROM 'tbl_' + (@level + 1) + 'items' WHERE url IS NOT NULL
```

ect. until last level.

can it be done?

plz let me know if i am not clear enough

Comment: Ooh, that is *icky* because of the dynamic schema (namely the table names encode the level). Normally, CTEs (command table expressions) are useful for recursion, but the dynamic schema requires the use of EXEC/sp_executesql or so - and I'm not sure if such is allowed in a CTE. Please say the schema can be updated?? If the schema *can't* be altered, consider making a *view* that flattens all the tables (it would hard-code in all the table names and required joins for the 7 tables) into something that is more easy to deal with (namely a self-recursive parent-child relation/tabke).

Comment: Whoops, CTE=Common Table Expression and a CTE dealing with recursion is a Recursive CTE.

Comment: From what i see, instead of creating a new table for each new level, wouldn't it be better create a self referenced table? Everything will be easier to manage.

Comment: all right, i cant change the schema, i'll try to do something with some flat view we got, thx user2864740

Answer (score 0):

```
select top 1 *
from
(
    select 1 as level, url from tbl_1_items where url IS NOT NULL
    union
    select 2 as level, url from tbl_2_items where url IS NOT NULL
    union
    select 3 as level, url from tbl_3_items where url IS NOT NULL
    union
    select 4 as level, url from tbl_4_items where url IS NOT NULL
    union ...
) v
order by level
```